# Webpage (Coinbase) data Scraping using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am a noob in Python and am currently in the process of trying to write some code that when I run it, will give me the price of bitcoin from Coinbase. Whenever I run the code, it says none instead of the price of Bitcoin.

Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.coinbase.com/dashboard')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

price = soup.find(id='id root')
assert isinstance(price, object)
bitcoin = soup.find('span',{'class':'BigAmount__AmountSuper-jnVzGG jdlzFZ'})

print(bitcoin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase needs you to login before showing the dashboard. It works in your browser because you've already logged in, so you will be directed to dashboard.

You can use https://www.coinbase.com/charts and class `PriceChart__HeadingPrice-iOthZP gLGtWx Flex__Flex-fVJVYW iDqRrV` to extract the Bitcoin price.

You can also use 
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR,INR to fetch bitcoin price in other currencies as well..

Comment: So I ran the code below in IDLE and PyCharm with the additions that you suggested and I got none as my result still. Is there anything that you can think of that I may still be doing wrong?